# Delete an specific element in an Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete an specific element in an array. I have this for example:
`A = [10,54,65,12]` and I want to delete the '65' number. How can I do this?

I try the pop() function but this deletes my last number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `splice()` with `indexOf()`

```js
var A = [10,54,65,12];

A.splice(A.indexOf(65), 1);
console.log(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the index of element using `.indexof()` and then remove it using `.splice()`:

```
var index = A.indexOf(65);
if (index > -1) {
  A.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `splice` & `indexOf`

```
var a = [10,54,65,12]
var index = a.indexOf(65);

if (index > -1) {
    a.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(a)
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/subuk1t0/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash library for doing this. '_.remove'

var A = [10,54,65,12];

_.remove(A, 65);

console.log(A)

// [10,54,12]

for more, check this  https://lodash.com/docs